# Paste together two dataframes element by element

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to paste, element by element, the contents of two data frames for input to another program. I have a data frame of means and a data frame of standard errors of the mean.

I tried using the R paste() function, but it doesn't seem to be able to cope with data frames. When using a vector, it seems to concatenate all the elements of the first vector into a string and all the elements of the second into a separate string. Instead, I need each reciprocal element in the two data frames to be concatenated together.

Any suggestions for how to approach this? I've included dummy input data (datMean and datSE) and my desired output (datNew). My real data frames are about 10 rows by 150 columns in size.

```
# means and SEM
datMean <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10, 3), b=rnorm(10, 3), d=rnorm(10, 3))
datSE <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10, 3)/100, b=rnorm(10, 3)/100, d=rnorm(10, 3)/100)

# what the output should look like
# i've chosen some arbitrary values here, and show only the first row. 
datNew <- data.frame(a="2.889-2.926", b="1.342-1.389", d="2.569-2.576")
```

The idea is for each element in datNew to be a range consisting of 'mean - se' and 'mean + se', separated by a dash '-' . The paste() function can do this for one element, how to do this over the whole dataframe?

```
paste(datMean[1,1] - datSE[1,1], datMean[1,1] + datSE[1,1], sep="-")
```

---

**EDIT 1:**
Looking at some of the answers I realize I left out an important bit of information in the question. Each row of the original data frames is named, and I need to reconstitute the final data frame with these names. For example:

```
rownames(datMean) <- LETTERS[1:10]
rownames(datSE) <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

I need datNew to eventually have these 10 rownames again. This could be problematic with some of the solutions using melt().

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you convert to matrices first, you can do it with no applies or loops at all.

```
MdatMean <- as.matrix(datMean)
MdatSE <- as.matrix(datSE)
matrix( paste(MdatMean - MdatSE, MdatMean + MdatSE, sep="-"), 
        nrow=nrow(MdatMean), dimnames=dimnames(MdatMean) )
```

You also might consider `formatC` for better formatting.

```
lo <- formatC(MdatMean - MdatSE, format="f", digits=3)
hi <- formatC(MdatMean + MdatSE, format="f", digits=3)
matrix( paste(lo, hi, sep="-"), 
        nrow=nrow(MdatMean), dimnames=dimnames(MdatMean) )
```

If you want a `data.frame` in the end just wrap the last line in `as.data.frame`.

Comment: many thanks for this - i've decided to accept this as the best answer because it doesn't rely on external packages and is faster than the alternatives, since it doesn't rely on apply or loops. + 1 for for formatC(), I hadn't seem that before and the formatting is much better.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to do this without manually specifying each column. First we make the data and put them in an array using the `abind` package, rounding to 3 because that looks better:

```
datMean <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10, 3), b=rnorm(10, 3), d=rnorm(10, 3))
datSE <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10, 3)/100, b=rnorm(10, 3)/100, d=rnorm(10, 3)/100)

library(abind)

datArray <- round(abind(datMean,datSE,along=3),3)
```

Then we can apply the `paste` function to each element and column of this array:

```
apply(datArray,1:2,function(x)paste(x[1]-x[2],"-",x[1]+x[2]))

      a               b               d              
 [1,] "3.537 - 3.581" "3.358 - 3.436" "3.282 - 3.312"
 [2,] "2.452 - 2.516" "1.372 - 1.44"  "3.041 - 3.127"
 [3,] "3.017 - 3.101" "3.14 - 3.228"  "5.238 - 5.258"
 [4,] "3.397 - 3.451" "2.783 - 2.839" "3.381 - 3.405"
 [5,] "1.918 - 1.988" "2.978 - 3.02"  "3.44 - 3.504" 
 [6,] "4.01 - 4.078"  "3.014 - 3.068" "1.914 - 1.954"
 [7,] "3.475 - 3.517" "2.117 - 2.159" "1.871 - 1.929"
 [8,] "2.551 - 2.619" "3.907 - 3.975" "1.588 - 1.614"
 [9,] "1.707 - 1.765" "2.63 - 2.678"  "1.316 - 1.348"
[10,] "4.051 - 4.103" "3.532 - 3.628" "3.235 - 3.287"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works really well, and is capable of retaining the rownames (see my edit). One question: is there a way to omit the space before and after the dash?

Comment: Excellent Idea!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I understand your problem. I melted the data for means and SE from multiple columns to one column using `reshape2::melt`.

```
library(reshape2)
datMean <- melt(datMean)$value
datSE <- melt(datSE)$value
dat <- cbind(datMean, datSE)

apply(X = dat, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {
            paste(x[1] - x[2], x[1] + x[2], sep = " - ")
        })
```

And the result

```
 [1] "3.03886802467251 - 3.08551547263516" 
 [2] "3.01803172559258 - 3.05247871975711" 
 [3] "3.4609230722069 - 3.56097173966387"  
 [4] "1.35368243309618 - 1.45548512578821" 
 [5] "2.39936853846605 - 2.47570756724791" 
 [6] "3.21849170272184 - 3.29653660329785"
```

*EDIT*

This solution respects your original data dimensions. What I do is make a 3D array and work on each cell at a time with holding the third dimension (`[x,y, 1:2]`) constant.

```
dat <- array(c(datMean, datSE), dim = c(10, 3, 2))

datNEW <- matrix(rep(NA, nrow(dat)*ncol(dat)), ncol = ncol(dat))

for (column in seq(ncol(dat))) {
    cls <- rep(NA, nrow(dat))
    for (rows in seq(nrow(dat))) {
        tmp <- dat[rows, column, 1:2]
        cls[rows] <- paste(tmp[1] - tmp[2], tmp[1] + tmp[2], sep = " - ")
    }
    datNEW[, column] <- cls
}
```

Comment: This works well, but I forgot to mention that I need datNew to have the same structure as the other data frames (same rownames and colnames - see my EDIT1). It seem difficult to do that with melt and cast.

Comment: Indeed, @Steve. See my edit that will follow in a few seconds.

Comment: ... also, you could split my first solution so that it would fit back into your dimensions.

Comment: this seems to work now, but i'm accepting Sacha's answer as it seems a bit simpler and requires less code. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I just added another solution to show the sweetness of 3D arrays. I was hoping someone would show me how to apply by holding one dimension constant, but you can't always have cake AND eat it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on every row at once, but you are applying to paired columns between two data.frames. Since you have a specific paste job to do each time, define the function:

```
pfun <- function(x, y) paste(x - y, x + y, sep = "-")
```

and then construct the new data.frame with the function:

```
 datNew <- data.frame(a = pfun(datMean$a, datSE$a), b = pfun(datMean$b, datSE$b), d = pfun(datMean$d, datSE$d))
```

There would be terser ways to apply this, but perhaps that helps you understand better. You can pass whole columns to paste, but not whole data.frames.

Use a loop to match all columns in the result without specifying them individually.

First create a list to store all the columns, we will convert to data.frame with the right column names.

```
datNew <- vector("list", ncol(datMean))
```

The naming does assume that column number, names and order are an exact match between the two input data.frames.

```
names(datNew) <- names(datMean)

for (i in 1:ncol(datMean)) {
    datNew[[i]] <- pfun(datMean[[i]], datSE[[i]])
}
```

Convert to data.frame:

```
datNew <- as.data.frame(datNew)
```

Comment: this works really well, thanks. For a data frame with 150+ columns it's going to be laborious though. I wonder if there's a way to automate it further...

Answer (score 0):

Using *mapply* to *paste* and *cbind* to keep *rownames*:

```
x <- cbind(
  datMean[, 0],
  mapply(paste, round(datMean - datSE, 3), round(datMean + datSE, 3), sep = " - "))

x
#               a             b             d
# A 3.268 - 3.321 5.226 - 5.308   2.3 - 2.358
# B 3.795 - 3.874 1.772 - 1.833 2.265 - 2.335
# C 1.305 - 1.346 1.238 - 1.291 2.812 - 2.874
# D 1.957 - 2.041 3.016 - 3.057 2.402 - 2.473
# E  4.73 - 4.786 2.909 - 2.963 2.245 - 2.297
# F 3.511 - 3.554 3.547 - 3.603 2.316 - 2.374
# G 3.601 - 3.689 3.073 - 3.144 3.145 - 3.215
# H 2.056 - 2.118  2.597 - 2.69  2.58 - 2.627
# I 1.802 - 1.835 2.794 - 2.895   2.452 - 2.5
# J 2.399 - 2.461 1.807 - 1.844 3.199 - 3.254

class(x)
# [1] "data.frame"
identical(rownames(datMean), rownames(x))
# [1] TRUE
```